# Datatables in Yii, Using Ajax

Tags: ajax, yii, datatables

I'm trying to use the EDatatables extension for Yii and specifically am wondering where the ajaxUrl should point to, and in general how I would actually go about handling the ajaxRequests?

The Datatable displays right now, but will not perform ajax based updates such as when trying to sort by a column or searching.

According to the [basic installation](https://code.google.com/p/edatatables/wiki/BasicUsage) page the default url is:

```
'ajaxUrl'       => Yii::app()->getBaseUrl().'/products/index',
```

I'm assuming this url is merely a placeholder and I'm meant to change it, but since I'm new to Datatables and Yii I have no idea how I should go about using Ajax. Could anyone help with this or point me in the correct direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just use:

```
Yii::app()->createUrl('controller/action',array('param'=>paramValue))
```

or

```
Yii::app()->createUrl('module/controller/action',array('param'=>paramValue))
```

hope it helps